# Transform dictionary with ddmmYYYY values into a Dataframe with counts per mmYYYY in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I would like to transform the dictionary below

```
x = {
'John': ['1.12.2021','2.12.2021','3.02.2022','4.2.2022','5.07.2022','6.07.2022','7.12.2022','8.12.2022'],
'Andrew': ['1.12.2021','2.03.2022','3.03.2022','4.05.2022','5.05.2022','6.09.2022','7.09.2022','8.11.2022','9.12.2022','10.12.2022']}
```

into a DataFrame like this, with columns that will show counts per Month

```
 Name  12.2021  02.2022  03.2022  05.2022  07.2022  09.2022  11.2022  \
  John        2        2        0        0        2        0        0   
Andrew        1        0        2        2        0        2        1   

12.2022  
      2  
      2
```

I started with this this, transforming the values into datetimes :

```
x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x, 'index').reset_index().fillna(value='0')
x.iloc[:,1:] = pd.to_datetime(x.iloc[:,1:], format='%d.%m.%Y')
print(x)
```

But getting this error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: I really you have the day first, there are only dates of December and I don't get the output

Comment: @mozway thank you for the comment, pasted the wrong dictionary,fixed it now.

Comment: OK, then I updated my answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary comprehension and `pandas.concat`+`unstack`:

###### day first

```
(pd.concat({k: pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(v), dayfirst=True)
                 .dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
                 .value_counts()
            for k,v in x.items()})
   .unstack(fill_value=0)
 )
```

output:

```
        2021-12  2022-02  2022-03  2022-05  2022-07  2022-09  2022-11  2022-12
John          2        2        0        0        2        0        0        2
Andrew        1        0        2        2        0        2        1        2
```

###### previous answer: month first (before data update)

```
(pd.concat({k: pd.Series(v, dtype='datetime64[ns]')
                 .dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
                 .value_counts()
            for k,v in x.items()})
   .unstack(fill_value=0)
 )
```

output:

```
        2021-01  2021-02  2021-03  2021-04  2021-05  2021-06  2021-07  2021-08  2021-09  2021-10
John          1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        0        0
Andrew        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1
```